# Split StudlyCaps string into words

Tags: php, regex

I need to figure out a way to split strings (examples below) into space separated words with php/regex. Below are some examples of strings and my expected output:

SomeRANDOMString -> Some RANDOM String
ANOTHERRandomString -> ANOTHER Random String
ACRONYM -> ACRONYM
String -> String

My current non-working solution so far is:

```
$title = preg_replace("/([a-z])([A-Z])/", "$1 $2", $title);
```

which outputs the strings above as:

Some RANDOMString
ANOTHERRandom String
ACRONYM
String

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$title = implode(' ', preg_split('/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?=[A-Z][a-z])/',
                                 $title, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)));
```

The `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])` portion of the regex will match when the previous character is lowercase and the next character is uppercase, so this will cause a split at the correct place for strings like `'SomeRANDOM'` or `'RandomString'`.  The `(?=[A-Z][a-z])` portion will match when the next two characters are an uppercase letter followed by a lowercase letter, this will cause a split in a string like `'ANOTHERRandom'`.  The `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag prevents a split at the very beginning of the string and `implode()` is used to convert the array returned by `preg_split()` to a space-delimited string.